# Is there netbeans version of m2eclipse workspace resolution feature?

Tags: netbeans, maven, netbeans-plugins

I colleague of mine uses m2eclipse workspace resolution, and I find it quite productive.

I'm wondering is there a netbeans version of mentioned behaviour?

UPDATE: definition of m2eclipse workspace resolution

> You can configure a project to resolve dependencies from a workspace. This has the effect of
>   altering the way that Maven locates dependency artifacts. If a project is configured to resolve
>   dependencies from the workspace, these artifacts do not need to be present in your local
>   repository. Assume that project-a and project-b are both in the same Eclipse workspace, and that
>   project-a depends on project-b. If workspace resolution is disabled, the m2eclipse Maven build
>   for project-a will only succeed if project-b's artifact is present in the local repository. If
>   workspace resolution is enabled, m2eclipse will resolve the dependency via the eclipse
>   workspace. In other words, when workspace resolution is enabled, project's don't have to be
>   installed in the local repository to relate to one another.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans too has built-in support for Maven.  See http://wiki.netbeans.org/Maven.

Comment: I know it has built-in support (I'm using it). But is there some way to achieve similar behaviour to eclipse workspace resolution?

Comment: I am sorry.  I misunderstood your post.  What do you mean by workspace resolution?  Dependency management(http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Dependency_management) maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I need, but since given link has improved my netbeans maven knowledge, +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: It is supported, but** ... `<projx>/build.xml` and `<projx>/nbproject` folders must be deleted/inexistent so the projects are recognized as Maven projects (blue *M* icons) and not as (ANT-based) Java projects (Coffee icons), e.g.:

- jump from *using project* (ugp) to *used project* (udp) via *CTRL + left click*
- immediate Javadoc updates in udp for ugp mouse code hovers
- up-to-date mvn ugp build on udp updates

---

Old investigation: There seems no support for this in [8.1 (Nov 2015)](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html) nor is it mentioned in the [NetBeans Maven FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ#Maven).

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_netbeans.htm) it is mentioned to be supported since 6.5, but does not work for us or is meant differently:

> NetBeans resolves Maven dependencies from its workspace without
>   installing to local Maven repository (requires dependency project be
>   in same workspace)

And there is an [*invalid* feature request (2011)](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197265) that may show some **alternatives** with implied pros and cons.

Comment: STRG means CTRL key?